# Change XML Node structure

Tags: xslt, tags

I have a result set structure such as

```
<ResultSets>
    <ResultSet rowCount="100">
        <Row>
            <InvoiceNr>12345</InvoiceNr>
            <InvoiceItem>0</InvoiceItem>
            <Year>2014</Year>
            <Month>201401</Month>
            <Week>201402</Week>
            <ItemCategory/>
            <BillingType/>
            <BPCodeSoldTo>123456</BPCodeSoldTo>
            <BPCodeShipTo/>
        </Row>
        <Row>
            <InvoiceNr>123452</InvoiceNr>
            <InvoiceItem>1</InvoiceItem>
            <Year>2014</Year>
            <Month>201401</Month>
            <Week>201402</Week>
            <ItemCategory/>
            <BillingType/>
            <BPCodeSoldTo>123452</BPCodeSoldTo>
            <BPCodeShipTo/>
            <BPCodeBillTo/>
        </Row>
    </ResultSet>
</ResultSets>
```

I would need to change the structure to

```
<io>
<row>
  <col>12345</col>
  <col>0</col>
  <col>2014</col>
  <col>201401</col>
  <col>201402</col>
  <col/>
  <col/>
  <col>123456</col>
  <col/>
  <col/>
</row>
<row>
  <col>123452</col>
  <col>1</col>
  <col>2014</col>
  <col>201401</col>
  <col>201402</col>
  <col/>
  <col/>
  <col>123452</col>
  <col/>
  <col/>
</row>
</io>
```

I have done it right now with (this is not the actual code, but a idea only) and it works. But is there a way to not explicitly ID the column tag name and have a statement that just capture all the child tag and put into  value  strucutre?

```
<row>
<xsl:foreach../RecordSets/RecordSet/Row>
  <col>
    <xsl:value of select = "InvoiceNr"/>
 </col>
<col>
<xsl:value of select = "InvoiceItem"/>
</col>
<col>
<xsl:value of select = "Year"/>
</col>
<col>
<xsl:value of select = "InvoiceNr"/>
 </col>
....
</xsl:foreach>
</row>
```

***Another question. in my original structure. I might have ResultSets/ResultSet or Just ResulSet (depend on the type of query it was ran) How do I ignore that and just say either ResultSets/ResultSet/Row or ResultSet/Row would work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> is there a way to not explicitly ID the column tag name and have a
>   statement that just capture all the child tag and put into value
>   strucutre?

Try it this way?

```
<xsl:template match="/">
    <io>
        <xsl:for-each select="ResultSets/ResultSet/Row">
            <row>
                <xsl:for-each select="*">
                    <col><xsl:value-of select="."/></col>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </row>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </io>
</xsl:template>
```

---

> I might have ResultSets/ResultSet or Just ResulSet (depend on the type
>   of query it was ran) How do I ignore that and just say either
>   ResultSets/ResultSet/Row or ResultSet/Row would work?

Use:

```
<xsl:for-each select="ResultSets/ResultSet/Row | ResultSet/Row">
```

---

> Oh.. one more thing. anyway to exclude certain tag in the
>    statement. like for example, select
>   everything except if tagname = `<EXEMPT_ID>`??

Yes, use a *predicate*:

```
<xsl:for-each select="*[not(self::EXEMPT_ID)]">
```

Comment: Brilliant, Are there any good books or resource to learn this? I really need to get a good gripe on XSLT and XPATH fast! 

But anyways. thank you so much!

Comment: @user3379902 I am sure there are, but I am not the right person to ask about that.

Comment: Oh.. one more thing. anyway to exclude certain tag in the <xsl:for-each select= "*"> statement. like for example, select everything except if tagname = <EXEMPT_ID>??